# How to check a MySQL connection in inno setup?

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I am making an install package by inno setup.
When running the package, it should connect to the MySQL server on localhost to create a database and import some tables.
How can I check the MySQL connection is valid and the connect options (user, password, and database name) configured by user’s input while running the package are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any native DLLs from Inno.  This includes a MySQL client library.